# How to get Item id after programmatically add Product to Cart?(Not in observer)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, addtocart, quoteitem

I want to add a product programmatically to the cart. My product is added by using the following code. But it didn't return the quote item id. How can I get the item id? Here is my code

```
$id = 100;
$qty = '2'; 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can be further simplified using the quote's addProduct method:

```
$id = 100;
$qty = 2;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

//Returns the newly created quote item or an error
$quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

//Collect totals and save the quote
$quote->collectTotals()->save();

//Grab the id from the new quote item
echo $quoteItem->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get quote id and quote's item id, you can get using below code.

```
$currentcart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$quote = $currentcart->getQuote();
$quoteItemId = $quote->getEntityId();
```

To get quote's item id

```
$quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
    $ItemId = $item->getId();
}
```